# Eclipse выдает ошибку при запуске приложения

Tags: eclipse, android, java

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту проблему

Вот ошибка, которая вылезает. Переустановил все что можно, но все равно не работает.

```
Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:136), pid=9804, tid=6908
  fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class

 JRE version:  (7.0_55-b13) (build )
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 D:\ANDROID\My_Works\AndroidLessons\hs_err_pid9804.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Comment: Удалите 64 разрядный и установите 32 разрядный jdk

Answer (score 1):

[На so этот вопрос быстро находится](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030111/fatal-error-invalid-layout-of-java-lang-string-at-value)
Вкратце - запустить как android application или удалить библиотеку андроида из конфигурации.

Comment: Супер, спасибо! Наконец-то все заработало